# How to return the highest digit from a number in a column in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe DF1 with two columns like below

```
Id           delq 
1       114321134522   
2       220033445576  
3       554721100333  
4       776234167521
```

I want to create a third column which will capture the highest digit from the values in delq field..so I need something like below

```
Id      delq        flag    
1    114321134522     5  
2    220033445576     7  
3    554421160333     6  
4    776234169521     9
```

Also I want to create multiple columns each capturing the digits from this number something like below

```
Id   Delq          flag1  flag2 flag3 flag4 ...so on 
1  114321134522   1       1     4     3 ....  
2  220033445576   2       2     0     0...  
3  554421160333   5       5      4     4...  
4  776234169521   7       7      6     2
```

Couldn't find a way to do this.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Tell us what you already tried and what is not working

Comment: `strsplit()` splits strings on characters: `sapply(rownames(mtcars), function(x) {max(c(as.integer(grep("\\d", unlist(strsplit(x, "", perl=TRUE)), value=TRUE))), 0)})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can `split` the 'delq' into individual elements, convert it to `numeric` and get the `max` value

```
sapply(strsplit(as.character(DF1$delq), ""), function(x) max(as.numeric(x)))
```

Regarding capturing the digits, just do the `strsplit` and `rbind` the `list` elements after converting to `numeric`

```
res <- do.call(rbind, lapply(strsplit(as.character(DF1$delq), ""), as.numeric))
names(res) <- paste0("Flag", seq_along(res))
cbind(DF1, res)
```

Also, we can use `read.fwf`

```
cbind(DF1, read.fwf(textConnection(as.character(DF1$delq)),
                             widths= rep(1, max(nchar(DF1$delq)))))
#   Id         delq V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12
#1  1 114321134522  1  1  4  3  2  1  1  3  4   5   2   2
#2  2 220033445576  2  2  0  0  3  3  4  4  5   5   7   6
#3  3 554721100333  5  5  4  7  2  1  1  0  0   3   3   3
#4  4 776234167521  7  7  6  2  3  4  1  6  7   5   2   1
```

As @DavidArenburg mentioned, the `widths` can specified with

```
as.integer(sapply(strsplit(as.character(DF1$delq), ""), max))
```

Comment: interesting as to why `cSplit` wont work here. Is `''` not considered a delimeter?

Comment: @Sotos May be it is not considered.  But replacing it with another delimiter works `cSplit(transform(DF1, delq = gsub("(?<=.)(?=.)", ",", delq, perl = TRUE)), "delq", ",")`

Comment: Yeah, my first thought was doing that (but with `strsplit(paste(...))` since I am a bit regex blind). It looks uncomfortable though.

Comment: You don't need to convert them to integer per row because the ASCII representation for digits is in increasing order, so just `as.integer(sapply(strsplit(as.character(df$delq), ""), max))` should do too

Comment: @DavidArenburg  Thanks David.  You are a great guy!

Comment: Thanks akrun..for your answer on the second question in the dataframe the 12 columns are getting created with column names as 1, 2, 3...12 is there a way to get the column names like mth1, mth2 or even V1, V2 as you have shown in your example output..

Comment: @SB `read.fwf` can take `col.names` as argument.  So use `col.names = paste0("mth", 1:12))`

Comment: Thanks akrun read.fwf ,using col.names worked ..appreciate your help on this...

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest `data.table::tstrsplit` for both tasks as it allows you to easily vecotrize the process

```
library(data.table)

# First question
do.call(pmax.int, tstrsplit(df$delq, "", type.convert = TRUE, fixed = TRUE))
## [1] 5 7 6 9

## Or you could compare digits while they are characters 
## because ASCII for 0:9 is in increasing order
as.integer(do.call(pmax.int, tstrsplit(df$delq, "", fixed = TRUE)))
## [1] 5 7 6 9

## Second question
setDT(df)[, tstrsplit(delq, "", type.convert = TRUE, fixed = TRUE)]
#    V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12
# 1:  1  1  4  3  2  1  1  3  4   5   2   2
# 2:  2  2  0  0  3  3  4  4  5   5   7   6
# 3:  5  5  4  4  2  1  1  6  0   3   3   3
# 4:  7  7  6  2  3  4  1  6  9   5   2   1
```

Comment: Thanks David ..your solution works as well ...appreciate your help on this